# Android Studio In-App purchases configuration

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am setting up in-app purchases for my application and am stuck at a particular point. The code I have used so far is as follows:

```
IabHelper mHelper;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);  //base64EncodedPublicKey is a string declared earlier and not reposted here.

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + result);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IAB setup Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Worked");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IAB setup Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final List additionalSkuList = new ArrayList();
                additionalSkuList.add("remove_ad");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    });
```

At this point, everything seems to be going well. The "Worked" section of code triggers and is processed successfully.  The code sends a request at this point to `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync`, which is configured as follows, outside of `onCreate()`:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Query Listener Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String removalPrice =
                inventory.getSkuDetails("remove_ad").getPrice();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, removalPrice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // update the UI
    }
};
```

At this point, Toast triggers to say "Query Listener Error", indicating that if (result.isFailure()) has triggered.  This is where I am stuck.  It is not giving me any clues as to why this might be happening.

From the Developer Console, these are the details of my In-App product:

```
Name/ID: Remove Ad (remove_ad)   
Type: Managed product 
Last Update: Jul 15, 2015  
Status: Active
```

What have I done incorrectly?  The only thing I am not too sure about is how I have declared and used my `arrayList`, and where I have submitted a string value to `.getPrice();`

Comment: In App purchase code are not run in emulator please run in phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Activity.this, SKU, 11,
                                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
```

Call this method and implement listner like below in that you will get result

```
public IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
            Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            }
            return;

    }
};
```

Refer the below link:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial